# Avoid overwriting values of a list - Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a list of values that I am plotting and every time I loop through the list, I create a plot. However, the plots overwrite every time it goes through the loop. This is what I tried for far that did not work.

```
myPath = "//my/absolute/path"

for i in list_val:
    i.plot('var1', 'var2')
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(myPath,''.join("figure{y}.png".format(y = i))))
    plt.show()
```

However, when I tried the following, it overwrites the images(which I knew it would happen),

```
myPath = "//my/absolute/path"

for i in list_val:
    i.plot('var1', 'var2')
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(myPath,''.join("figure.png")))
    plt.show()
```

How can I modify my first snippet above to avoid overwriting images?

Comment: list_val is a list of dataframes?  In the first snippet, what is the resulting name of the png that is saved?

Comment: @saintsfan342000 yes, it is a list of data frames ,I named my resulting images as `figure` for example. I am searching to add like `figure1` `figure2` etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
myPath = "//my/absolute/path"

for index,df in enumerate(list_val):
    df.plot('var1', 'var2')
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(myPath,''.join("figure{y}.png".format(y = index))))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I had the `j` and `i` switched, it was my careless mistake, now, it works just fine :)

Comment: Yeah, probably a bad idea not to put them alphabetically on my part i updated

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
myPath = "//my/absolute/path"

for i in range(1, len(list_val)):
    list_val[i].plot('var1', 'var2')
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(myPath,''.join("figure{y}.png".format(y = i+1))))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: this method throws an error `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`, I think using `range` like this won't work, probably, it should be `for i in range(1, len(list_val)):`, which will actually give the `range`.